# how to read message in reject(r => new Error({ id, message: 'target'}));

Tags: javascript, node.js

How do I read the Error object message in the catch?
...

```
reject(result = new Error({id, message:'target'}));
```

...

```
.catch(e => Promise.resolve( /* display the message here */ );
```

Comment: Don't you mean `reject(new Error(...))`?

Comment: Your title correctly has `message: 'target'` but the code you've shared uses `error: 'target'` which is not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`message` property of the error object contains the error message. In your case the message is `"[object Object]"` as the `Error` constructor expects a string but your are passing an object. Default string representation of an object is `"[object Object]"`. You can use `JSON.stringify` for converting the object into a string: `new Error(JSON.stringify{id, message:'target'})`. Now for reading object properties you should parse the error message by using `JSON.parse`.

Another option is setting new properties for the error object:

```
const error = new Error('error message'); 
error.id = id;
reject(error);
```

Comment: yeah, this is what i'm getting, how do i extract

Comment: this is the way to go (2nd option), thanks. I made it more complicated than that it really was. Thanks for the extra insight to make it work the other way.

Answer (score 4):

Just try with `e.message` which will let you access to the error object data that you pass to `Error`.